# "Provisioning profile does not match the developer certificate" error when setting up GreenhouseCI

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, mobileprovision, greenhouseci

Trying to set up a new app in GreenhouseCI and running into an error when attempting to input the Provisioning profile and Certificate files. The error states:

Provisioning profile does not match the developer certificate

I exported my private developer key and have downloaded the mobile provisioning file from the Apple Developer portal. But when I try to save I get the following error:

[GreenhouseCI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUmXL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - it's important to make sure that the mobile provisioning file is created under the 'Development' section and NOT the 'Distribution' section. Either select an existing Development profile or create a new one, and add your personal certificate to the profile. Download that file and upload to GreenhouseCI.

[Apple Developer center screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL75h.png)

Comment: still gives me the same problem, its interesting to note that it was working normally for a long time until recently when I started having the same issues